# What does "one" refer to and what does this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, pronouns

I wonder if the word **"one"** in the following sentence refers to **"face"**?

> “What did you just say?” Tony’s very angry **face** was **in** Peter’s very
>   embarrassed **one**.
>
> “I take it back.”

And if I were right, what does this whole sentence mean? I am very very confused by the usage of **"in"** here. Is it even common to say **"somebody's face be in somebody's face"**? Could any one help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"One" seems to refer to Peter's face.

We can break it down:

> Peter's (noun - belonging to) very embarrassed (adjective) [one](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB848GB848&q=Dictionary#dobs=one) (pronoun - referring to a person or thing previously mentioned or easily identified).

As @Christian mentioned, to be "in [someones] face" is an idiom that means to have an aggressive attitude towards them. I believe [this](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+someone%27s+face) link is better in the context being used above.

Comment: thanks a lot, the link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "one" refers to "face".

Regarding the "in" that confuses you, read the first meaning in https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+(one%27s)+face .

The subject, which here is "Tony’s very angry face", is physically in front of Peter's face.

Like when you get with your face closer to someone else's when you're about to get angry.